# How do I convert this json to yml

Tags: python, json, yaml

I have this `list` of `dict`ionaries and want to convert it into `.yml` file:

```
input = [
    {
        'id': 1, 
        'coordinates': [
            [34, 31], 
            [235, 31], 
            [34, 97], 
            [235, 97]
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'id': 2, 
        'coordinates': [
            [1028, 31], 
            [1248, 31], 
            [1028, 104], 
            [1248, 104]
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my code:

```
import json
import yaml
coord = [{'id': 1, 'coordinates': [[34, 31], [235, 31], [34, 97], [235, 97]]}, {'id': 2, 'coordinates': [[1028, 31], [1248, 31], [1028, 104], [1248, 104]]}]
print(coord)
ff = open('data.yml', 'w')
yaml.dump(coord, ff, default_flow_style=False)

ydump = yaml.dump(coord, default_flow_style=False)
print ('ydump=',ydump)
f.close()
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
ydump= - coordinates:
  - - 34
    - 31
  - - 235
    - 31
  - - 34
    - 97
  - - 235
    - 97
  id: 1
- coordinates:
  - - 1028
    - 31
  - - 1248
    - 31
  - - 1028
    - 104
  - - 1248
    - 104
  id: 2
```

Whereas required output is:

[image]

I also tried this code to see if it works:

```
with open("test.yml", "w+") as output:
        output.write("-\n          id: " + str(id) + "\n          coordinates: [" 
                         + "[" + str([xywh[0]) + "," + str(xywh[1]) + "]," + "]]\n")
                          "[" + str(xywh[0]+xywh[2]) + "," + str(xywh[1]) + "]," +
                          "[" + str(xywh[0]) + "," + str(xywh[1]+xywh[3]) + "]," +
                          "[" + str(xywh[0]+xywh[2]) + "," + str(xywh[1]+xywh[3]) + "]]\n")
```

But getting this error:

```
 + "[" + str([xywh[0]) + "," + str(xywh[1]) + "]," + "]]\n")
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I posted my code snippet and proper input output, still why am i being downvoted ?

Comment: Please (for the voters) provide the idownvotedbecau.se link, Ankita has only asked one question before.

Comment: Are you trying to get it in order?

Comment: Your original code uses `f.close()` which should throw an error, as you open the output file and assign to`ff`. You should also not use `UPDATE` or `EDIT` in your questions. Keep the question one coherent whole that is better for future visitors. Anyone interested in how your question  evolved can look at the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course write YAML as a text file, but it is cumbersome
to make things generic. PyYAML doesn't have have built-in fine control
over flow style but `ruamel.yaml` does. PyYAML also only supports YAML 1.1, which was
superseded in 2009. (disclaimer: I author of ruamel.yaml).

The only thing you need to do is specify that the sequence/list that is the value
of coordinates needs to be dumped as flow-style:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def FSS(seq):
    res = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(seq)
    res.fa.set_flow_style()
    return res

input = [
    {
        'id': 1, 
        'coordinates': FSS([
            [34, 31], 
            [235, 31], 
            [34, 97], 
            [235, 97]
        ])
    }, 
    {
        'id': 2, 
        'coordinates': FSS([
            [1028, 31], 
            [1248, 31], 
            [1028, 104], 
            [1248, 104]
        ])
    }
]


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(input, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- id: 1
  coordinates: [[34, 31], [235, 31], [34, 97], [235, 97]]
- id: 2
  coordinates: [[1028, 31], [1248, 31], [1028, 104], [1248, 104]]
```

If you cannot easily change the definition of `input`, you can also use:

```py
for inp in input:
    inp['coordinates'] = FSS(inp['coordinates'])
    inp['coordinates'] = FSS(inp['coordinates'])
```

Please note that the [recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files
has been `.yaml` since
September 2006.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: add `sort_keys=False`

```
ydump = yaml.dump(coord, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: That's not the answer, you are only explaining how to avoid key sorting...

Comment: Please check sir, I just updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot everyone. This snippet solved my problem:

```py
with open("test.yml", "w+") as output:
    output.write("-\n          id: " + str(ctr) + "\n          coordinates: [" 
               + "[" + str(xywh[0]) + "," + str(xywh[1]) + "]," + 
                 "[" + str(xywh[0] + xywh[2]) + "," + str(xywh[1]) + "]," +
                 "[" + str(xywh[0]) + "," + str(xywh[1] + xywh[3]) + "]," +
                 "[" + str(xywh[0] + xywh[2]) + "," + str(xywh[1] + xywh[3]) + "]]\n")
```

Comment: It's a shame about the down votes but this is a bad answer, even if the OP used this answer for themselves that's a poor result. @anton's answer is good and should ideally be used by the OP and selected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy-paste your `JSON` string into [`this converter`](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter), and that's what happened:

[image]

This probably means that the standard `.yml` file doesn't format Python `list`s that way.

Comment: updated the code sir

Comment: So you are like trying to create an encoder by yourself? Are you aware that the Python parser won't be able to decode your personal version of YAML?

Comment: Apart from having the usual online formatting issues. That online formatter has severe problems and changes data without warning. You shouldn't use it.